# Removing two specific elements and all elements between in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, artifact

I'm working with a tracking software that tracks objects on an xy coordinate plane. I've been using this to calculate the change in position in the y coordinate, however I have some artifacts left over from the tracking software. Typically the tracker will jump to a corner, remain there for a few frames, and jump back. My data will end up looking something like this:

```
yposition <- c(400,402,403,404,405,407,80,81,83,80,402,401,399,397, 398, 398, 653, 653, 654, 395, 392, 391)
dataframe <- data.frame(yposition)
velocity <- c(0,2,1,1,1,2,327,1,2,2,-322, -1,-1, -2, 1, 0, -255, 0, 1, 259, -3, -1)
dataframe <- cbind(dataframe,velocity)
```

The artifacts in this case would be when yposition jumps to 80 and back, and when it jumps to 653 and back. Is there a way to remove the changeinposition values corresponding to these artifacts (in this case, the elements from 327 to -322, and the elements from -255 to 259)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky in practice because it is not clear how to identify you base level as opposed to jump.

If we assume that you series always start from `normal` level, you could use combination of `diff` and `cumsum` to exclude jumps from the signal:

```r
jump.level <-  150 # this value is arbitrary
yposition[abs(cumsum(c(0, diff(yposition)))) < jump.level]
# [1] 400 402 403 404 405 407 402 401 399 397 398 398 395 392 391
```

To filter you data.frame you can extract indexes of elements that match condition above with `which`:

```r
i <- which(abs(cumsum(c(0, diff(yposition)))) < jump.level)
dataframe[i, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If removal is based on velocity, we need to remove rows and following rows where speed is changed abruptly until meeting another abrupt change.:

```r
# threshold for velocity
threshold <- 5
isAbnormal <- abs(dataframe$velocity) > threshold
indexes <- which(isAbnormal)
```

Since the starting and ending rows that we need to remove always appear in pairs, so we know that we need to remove rows from 7 to 11 and from 17 to 20.

```r
> indexes 
[1]  7 11 17 20
```

We need to remove two pairs(`7:11` and `17:20`):

```r
pairs <- split(indexes,rep(1:(length(indexes)/2),times = 1,each = 2))
```

```r
> pairs
$`1`
[1]  7 11

$`2`
[1] 17 20
```

Convert pairs to a vector, and remove those rows:

```r
remove_rows <- Reduce(
    function(x,y) c(x,y),
    Map(function(x) x[1]:x[2],pairs)
)
```

```r
> remove_rows
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 17 18 19 20
```

```r
> dataframe[-remove_rows,]
   yposition velocity
1        400        0
2        402        2
3        403        1
4        404        1
5        405        1
6        407        2
12       401       -1
13       399       -1
14       397       -2
15       398        1
16       398        0
21       392       -3
22       391       -1
```